# Adding new layout, fragment or new Acitvity?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating app with 20 pages (swiping from page to page) and after reading some info I finally got mixed up on what is the best solution to use.

1. create only new layouts and add them to the same one MainActivity?
2. create every time new Activity + new layout?
3. create fragments and add them to the same one MainActivity?

What's the actual difference between fragments and layouts?

What is the code in Java to use for adding new layouts/fragments?

Thanks.

Comment: this might be of interest to you http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: Thank you Majeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an activity main page as like below for using Fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.myproj.activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:name="com.example.HomeFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

//Design ur fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true">
.....
.....
.....
</LinearLayout>
```

//JAVA

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             ...
              // call MyFragment page here
            }
    .....
    .....
    .....
    }
```

//Fragment

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
        View view;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstantState){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page,container,false);
    ...

      return view;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here is my vote up for your post Shunmugapriya.

Comment: Happy to hear.. If u got the answer, pls click the tick.. By ur vote, others can also get benefited

Answer (score 0):

Layouts are just xml resources that defines how a layout should look alike on screen. Fragments are entirely different. Think of fragments as mini-activities that have layouts associated with them. Just like activities, when fragments are created, they inflate a layout and then render that layout. Fragments however needs to be attached to an Activity, and they cannot exist without it.

For you, the best solution would be to use fragments within a `ViewPager`, this enables you to swipe from left to right (or vice versa) and have infinite number of pages

Comment: Thanks Isuru. Will this allow to save data from each page (pressed radio button) and store it in memory until the 20th page?

Comment: Yes, activity that contain all the fragments keep them in memory until you explicitly ask them to detach.

Comment: Cool. Many thanks :) Let's see how it works now.